# R How to generate an incremental sequence based on a time segmented sequence

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert a data file of the form 'initial.df' to 'final.df' and my skills in programming and R are being seriously tested. I continue to try various approaches but without success.

```
# minimal initial data structure
initial.df = cbind.data.frame(dtime = as.POSIXct(c("12:30", "12:31", "12:32", 
              "13:10","13:11","13:12","20:14","20:15", "20:160"), format="%H:%M"),
              flow=c(120, 100, 90, 110, 100, 95, 115, 100, 95))
initial.df

# minimal final data structure
final.df = cbind.data.frame(initial.df, cycle=c(rep(1, 3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3)))
final.df
```

As background, the data file is data logged from a membrane bioreactor every minute during filtration and there are filtration gaps that separate each cycle. Each cycle runs for several hours. Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Vince
Thanks,
Vince

Updated data set to better reflect the actual type of data:

```
 initial.df = cbind.data.frame(dtime = as.POSIXct(c("2015-12-18 23:58",
    "2015-12-18 23:59", "2015-12-19 00:01", "2015-12-19 00:02", "2015-12-19 4:58",
    "2015-12-19 04:59", "2015-12-19 05:00", "2015-12-19 05:01", "2015-12-19 5:02",
    "2015-12-19 07:59", "2015-12-19 08:00", "2015-12-19 08:01", "2015-12-19 8:02"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), flow=c(120, 100, 90, 80, 75, 110, 100, 95, 85,  115, 100, 95, 90))
    initial.df

# final data structure
final.df = cbind.data.frame(initial.df, cycle=c(rep(1, 4), rep(2,5), rep(3,4)))
final.df
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this gives me some ideas, but it only provides a unique index for each hour. The cycle may go for more than 1-hour and it's unknown in advance the exact length of the cycle except that it's generally separated by more than 1-hour. Vince

Comment: Can you test the solutions in the answer I posted?  If you are getting different results, please consider to post a more representative example and expected output.

Comment: @akrun...working on getting a more representative example up shortly.thanks

Comment: can you check `cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(cut(initial.df$dtime, breaks='1 hour', labels=FALSE))>1))` this?

Comment: @akrun...YES it works! Thanks a million...saved me several hours of tedious work. Vince p.s. unfortunately don't have enough points to +++...your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `cut` the 'dtime' with `breaks` specified as '1 hour' to create a grouping variable, then get the difference between adjacent elements (`diff`), check which element is greater than 1, and calculate the cumulative sum after appending `TRUE` value at the beginning (as the `diff` output length is 1 less than the length of the 'dtime' column)

```
initial.df$cycle <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(cut(initial.df$dtime, 
                            breaks='1 hour', labels=FALSE))>1))
```

Comment: @nongkrong thanks! My initial minimal data was not very clear but updated dataset should help. Can't use the flow since its too erratic. Vince

Comment: Problem solved by **akrun**...much appreciated and for the clear explanation!